# How to use threejs with phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, three.js

The questing is very self-describing. I have tested with a simple 3D cube. it works fine in browser. but just displays a blank page in emulator.

Some says that threejs does not work with phonegap, but some others say they used and it works fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android you can either use the Chrome app to show your webpage or use phonegap/cordova and used the embedded WebView.

Until Lollipop the default WebView depended on OS updates, now on devices from Lollipop (5.x) and up there is a 'Android System WebView' which is updated.

From this page:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview
You can see that WebGL support wasn't added until WebView v36.

On emulator I don't believe that WebGL is supported in the WebView but you should be able to use it on devices with Lollipop and higher.

**EDIT 2015-12-02**

One other possibility if you want to use WebGL on Android devices lower than Lollipop (5.x) you could include your own browser component.

The [Crosswalk Project](https://crosswalk-project.org/) would be something to look at to allow for more devices to run your WebGL code.

Do note the WebGL limitations listed here:
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Canvas-and-WebGL-support

Comment: For me the only deference between Lolipop and the older versions,that Lolipop displays a black background as I created it, while the older displays a white one. :D

Comment: but it might be an emulator problem as you said, will test and see

Comment: And yes it worked perfectly fine on device, any idea how to test it also in emulator? any work around?